# Using getNeighboringCellInfo() in Android Q API 29 gives error "Cannot resolve method" instead of deprecation warning

Tags: android

I have a code that uses getNeighboringCellInfo() method from android.telephony.TelephonyManager that works fine in Android Studio with compileSdkVersion set to 28, but when I set compileSdkVersion to 29 I get error "Cannot resolve method" instead of deprecation warning since this method is removed in API 29. The result is that project can not be built.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
List<NeighboringCellInfo> n=telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();
```

Comment: Read here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/NeighboringCellInfo

Comment: @NileshRathod I see it is written "This class should not be used by any app targeting Android Q or higher", but I'd like to use same app for phones with Android Q and previous Android versions (with this method supported). The normal way is to give deprecation warning and to be able to build project, not "Cannot resolve method" error which prevents project from building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NeighboringCellInfo` class was deprecated in Android Q (thus discouraged but still available for use), but `TelephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo()` was apparently deprecated previously, and was **removed** from Android Q. It no longer appears in the Android docs at all. Quote below is an official response from [a related bug on the Android Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128553845#comment5):

> "A @removed method is not intended to be available in the sdk.  As
>   mentioned in the docs, we suggest to use getAllCellInfo instead.
>
> We @deprecated this function 2 years ago.  The alternative
>   (getAllCellInfo) function was created 7 years ago. It should be
>   available on the older devices you need to support."

The official solution provided [on a duplicate issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129801046#comment3) is to use reflection:

> The recommended approach would be to detect the API version in use and
>   use the new method where available, otherwise to use reflection to
>   access the old method if needed.